# Enabling AD LDAP to Strapi

Tags: active-directory, ldap, strapi, windows-server

**System Information**

- Strapi Version: 4.17.0
- Operating System: Windows Server 2019
- Database: postgreSQL
- Node Version: v20.11.0
- NPM Version: 10.3.0
- Yarn Version:

Hi friends , I’ve been searching across all the internet and I can’t find a way to implement LDAP authentication in Strapi (for the admin panel). Any help is very welcome , thanks friends

I have been reading thins post but some libraries doesn't exist:
https://www.restack.io/docs/strapi-knowledge-strapi-ldap-authentication-guide